# What actually a block contains, is the data inside it a virtual or physical entity?

Tags: blockchain, blocks

My understanding of a block in blockchain is that it is a data structure that contains information like Block Size, Block Header, Transaction Counter and then Transactions. Deeper in the Block Header we have information like Previous Block Hash, Merkle Root, Timestamp, Difficulty Target and Nonce.

Recently, I appeared for an interview and my above explanation of what actually makes a block in blockchain was not very much accepted by the interviewer and he quoted that my response was not up to the mark.

Though my question is not related to coding per se, I wish to clear my concepts here. Will appreciate if someone can guide me here as to what could have been the best technical answer in my case. Will appreciate a pointer to an article or any other document which explains these underlying concepts in details.

Comment: What mean `deeper`? All that info is just in block. Did interviwer give you own explanation? The block itself contains another data which you're not denoted https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_getBlockByNumber.

Comment: By 'deeper' I meant more 'detailed' explanation preferably on the technical or coding side. Unfortunately, the interviewer didn't explain his side and advised me to acquire more knowledge of the concept.

Comment: Maybe he has wrong undestanding? :) your explanation is LGTM.

Comment: Pardon me please, the structure that I have explained in my question is not based on some specific order of 'significance' or 'importance' of each component making 'nonce' the least significant one as it in the last details.

Comment: Yep I get why you think that. I hope someone else has a better answer than me.  Just listing terms is one way to answer. But I would prefer an answer ordered by significance with a quick explanation of the purpose of each that doesnt sound memorized